# Exibindo valor de checkbox desabilitados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Olá, eu criei um sistema bem simples onde eu habilito 10 valores de 25 e quero que ele exiba com um innerHTML os que estão desabilitados, fiz esse sistema com checkbox e fui colocando elas em variáveis e depois fazendo if de uma por uma.

Sou iniciante em programação e sei que possa existir uma forma mais simples de fazer isso, segue o exemplo do sistema abaixo.

Sistema funcionando: http://visitantes.hol.es/loto/

```js
//DEFININDO VARIÃVEIS GLOBAIS (SEM O "var")
  r1 = document.getElementById("myRadio01");
  r2 = document.getElementById("myRadio02");
  r3 = document.getElementById("myRadio03");
  r4 = document.getElementById("myRadio04");
  r5 = document.getElementById("myRadio05");
  r6 = document.getElementById("myRadio06");
  r7 = document.getElementById("myRadio07");
  r8 = document.getElementById("myRadio08");
  r9 = document.getElementById("myRadio09");
  r10 = document.getElementById("myRadio10");
  r11 = document.getElementById("myRadio11");
  r12 = document.getElementById("myRadio12");
  r13 = document.getElementById("myRadio13");
  r14 = document.getElementById("myRadio14");
  r15 = document.getElementById("myRadio15");
  r16 = document.getElementById("myRadio16");
  r17 = document.getElementById("myRadio17");
  r18 = document.getElementById("myRadio18");
  r19 = document.getElementById("myRadio19");
  r20 = document.getElementById("myRadio20");
  r21 = document.getElementById("myRadio21");
  r22 = document.getElementById("myRadio22");
  r23 = document.getElementById("myRadio23");
  r24 = document.getElementById("myRadio24");
  r25 = document.getElementById("myRadio25");
  bgradio = document.getElementsByClassName("bgradio");
  exiberesultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

 function verificar() {
  resultado01 = document.getElementById("resultado01");
  resultado02 = document.getElementById("resultado02");
  resultado03 = document.getElementById("resultado03");
  resultado04 = document.getElementById("resultado04");
  resultado05 = document.getElementById("resultado05");
  resultado06 = document.getElementById("resultado06");
  resultado07 = document.getElementById("resultado07");
  resultado08 = document.getElementById("resultado08");
  resultado09 = document.getElementById("resultado09");
  resultado10 = document.getElementById("resultado10");
  resultado11 = document.getElementById("resultado11");
  resultado12 = document.getElementById("resultado12");
  resultado13 = document.getElementById("resultado13");
  resultado14 = document.getElementById("resultado14");
  resultado15 = document.getElementById("resultado15");
  resultado16 = document.getElementById("resultado16");
  resultado17 = document.getElementById("resultado17");
  resultado18 = document.getElementById("resultado18");
  resultado19 = document.getElementById("resultado19");
  resultado20 = document.getElementById("resultado20");
  resultado21 = document.getElementById("resultado21");
  resultado22 = document.getElementById("resultado22");
  resultado23 = document.getElementById("resultado23");
  resultado24 = document.getElementById("resultado24");
  resultado25 = document.getElementById("resultado25");
  btnImprimir = document.getElementById("btnImprimir");

  // Verifica se nÃ£o existe input selecionados
  if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
   alert("Selecione algum nÃºmero");
  document.getElementsByClassName("item-resultado").style.display = "none";
  }      

  if (r1.checked == false) {resultado01.innerHTML = "01";}
  if (r2.checked == false) {resultado02.innerHTML = "02";}
  if (r3.checked == false) {resultado03.innerHTML = "03";}
  if (r4.checked == false) {resultado04.innerHTML = "04";}
  if (r5.checked == false) {resultado05.innerHTML = "05";}
  if (r6.checked == false) {resultado06.innerHTML = "06";}
  if (r7.checked == false) {resultado07.innerHTML = "07";}
  if (r8.checked == false) {resultado08.innerHTML = "08";}
  if (r9.checked == false) {resultado09.innerHTML = "09";}
  if (r10.checked == false) {resultado10.innerHTML = "10";}
  if (r11.checked == false) {resultado11.innerHTML = "11";}
  if (r12.checked == false) {resultado12.innerHTML = "12";}
  if (r13.checked == false) {resultado13.innerHTML = "13";}
  if (r14.checked == false) {resultado14.innerHTML = "14";}
  if (r15.checked == false) {resultado15.innerHTML = "15";}
  if (r16.checked == false) {resultado16.innerHTML = "16";}
  if (r17.checked == false) {resultado17.innerHTML = "17";}
  if (r18.checked == false) {resultado18.innerHTML = "18";}
  if (r19.checked == false) {resultado19.innerHTML = "19";}
  if (r20.checked == false) {resultado20.innerHTML = "20";}
  if (r21.checked == false) {resultado21.innerHTML = "21";}
  if (r22.checked == false) {resultado22.innerHTML = "22";}
  if (r23.checked == false) {resultado23.innerHTML = "23";}
  if (r24.checked == false) {resultado24.innerHTML = "24";}
  if (r25.checked == false) {resultado25.innerHTML = "25";}
  btnImprimir.style.display = "initial";
  };

  function maisque10 () {
      // controla se tem mÃ­nimo 10 escolhidos
      $('form').on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
          if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length >= 10) {
              alert("Voce selecionou 10 numeros");
          }
      });
  }
  maisque10();

  function limpar() {
   if ($('.radiobuttons').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('.radiobuttons').prop('checked', false);
    $(bgradio).removeClass('bgradiochange');
    location.reload();
   }
  }
```

```css
 * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

   @media print { 
          .number { visibility:hidden; } 
          form { visibility:hidden; }
          .botoes { visibility:hidden; }
          h3 { visibility:hidden; }

        #resultado {
         visibility: visible;
         position: absolute;
         top:0;
         left:0;
     }
    }


.content {
 width: 1200px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

 #number {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 28pt;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .bgradio {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }

 .bgradiochange {
  background-color: black;
 }

 #resultado {
  width: 1200px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: verdana;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
 }

 .item-resultado {
  display: inline;
 }

 .botoes {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
 }

 #btnImprimir {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
 }

 input[type=checkbox] {
  padding: 10px;
 }

 .clear {
  clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Estudo</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 
<body>
<div class="content">
 <h3 class="text-center">Estudo</h3>
 <div id="number">
  <form name="form">
   <div class="bgradio">01<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio01" onclick="clicando01();" value="01" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">02<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio02" onclick="clicando01();" value="02" class="radiobuttons"></div> 
   <div class="bgradio">03<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio03" onclick="clicando01();" value="03" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">04<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio04" onclick="clicando01();" value="04" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">05<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio05" onclick="clicando01();" value="05" class="radiobuttons"></div><br>
   <div class="bgradio">06<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio06" onclick="clicando01();" value="06" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">07<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio07" onclick="clicando01();" value="07" class="radiobuttons"></div> 
   <div class="bgradio">08<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio08" onclick="clicando01();" value="08" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">09<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio09" onclick="clicando01();" value="09" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">10<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio10" onclick="clicando01();" value="10" class="radiobuttons"></div><br>
   <div class="bgradio">11<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio11" onclick="clicando01();" value="11" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">12<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio12" onclick="clicando01();" value="12" class="radiobuttons"></div> 
   <div class="bgradio">13<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio13" onclick="clicando01();" value="13" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">14<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio14" onclick="clicando01();" value="14" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">15<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio15" onclick="clicando01();" value="15" class="radiobuttons"></div><br>
   <div class="bgradio">16<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio16" onclick="clicando01();" value="16" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">17<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio17" onclick="clicando01();" value="17" class="radiobuttons"></div> 
   <div class="bgradio">18<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio18" onclick="clicando01();" value="18" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">19<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio19" onclick="clicando01();" value="19" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">20<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio20" onclick="clicando01();" value="20" class="radiobuttons"></div><br>
   <div class="bgradio">21<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio21" onclick="clicando01();" value="21" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">22<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio22" onclick="clicando01();" value="22" class="radiobuttons"></div> 
   <div class="bgradio">23<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio23" onclick="clicando01();" value="23" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">24<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio24" onclick="clicando01();" value="24" class="radiobuttons"></div>
   <div class="bgradio">25<input type="checkbox" id="myRadio25" onclick="clicando01();" value="25" class="radiobuttons"></div><br>
  </form>
 </div>

 <ul id="resultado">
   <li id="resultado01" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado02" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado03" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado04" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado05" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado06" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado07" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado08" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado09" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado10" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado11" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado12" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado13" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado14" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado15" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado16" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado17" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado18" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado19" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado20" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado21" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado22" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado23" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado24" class="item-resultado"></li>
   <li id="resultado25" class="item-resultado"></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="clear"></div>

 <div class="botoes">
  <button type="button" onclick="verificar();" id="btncheckar" class="btn btn-success">Veriricar</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="limpar();" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="print();" class="btn btn-default" id="btnImprimir">Imprimir</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/campos.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tudo bom Felipe, pelo que entendi você precisa validar os values e a situação de cada checkbox, pode usar o jQuery **$(".radiobuttons").each(function(){});** Nesta função o jQuery passara por todos checkbox com a classe "radiobuttons" ai é só pegar o value e a situação e ir imprimindo. funciona como um loop. Se for isso posso postar um exemplo.

Comment: É exatamente isso Cleverson!
Muito obrigado pelo exemplo dado irei estudar seu código e entender como funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo no jQuery se quiser aplicar no seu estudo:

*Pode modificar as validações do `if else` para sua necessidade exibir `alert`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3"/>
<button id="ir">Ir</button/>
<div class="result_check"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){ $("#ir").click(function(){
  $(".result_check").html("");
  $(".check").each(function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     var sit = $(this).prop("checked");
     if(val > 0 && sit == false){
        $(".result_check").append(val+" No Check ");
     }else{}
    });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Excelente resposta inclusive mostrando como se refatora o código de forma eficiente e semântica.

Comment: Excelente resposta, não respondi antes porque fiquei empolgado e me aprofundei ainda mais no assunto, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Refiz o seu código para você ter um exemplo de como pode ficar mais simples a sua logica.

Não refiz tudo do zero, apenas editei algumas partes que achei obvio usar loops e arrays.

> PS: Corrigi a sua função maisque10(). Adicionei o e.preventDefault(),
>   no seu codigo o usuário poderia continuar checkando os checkboxes
>   mesmo depois de ultrapassar o limite de 10

**JS:**

```
var $checkboxList = $('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    $resultadoList = $('.item-resultado'),
    $bgcb = $('.bgradio'),
    $exiberesultado = $('#resultado'),
    $btnImprimir = $("#btnImprimir");

function verificar() {
    // Verifica se nÃ£o existe input selecionados
    if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
        alert("Selecione algum número");
        document.getElementsByClassName("item-resultado").style.display = "none";
    }
    $exiberesultado.html('');
    $checkboxList.each(function(i){
        //mostra apenas os não selecionados
        if(this.checked == false){
            $exiberesultado.append('<li class="item-resultado">'+this.value+', </li>');
        }
    });
    $btnImprimir.css("display", "initial");
};

function maisque10 () {
    // controla se tem mÃ­nimo 10 escolhidos
    $('form').on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
        if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length >= 10) {
            alert("Voce selecionou 10 numeros");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
maisque10();

function limpar() {
    location.reload();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--
Observe que no elemento ul#resultado eu removi todo os li.resultado*
Eu estou desenhando dinamicamente no javascript na linha:
$exiberesultado.append('<li class="item-resultado">'+this.value+', </li>');
-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Estudo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
<div class="content">
    <h3 class="text-center">Estudo</h3>
    <div id="number">
        <form name="form">
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">01<input type="checkbox" value="01"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">02<input type="checkbox" value="02"></div>  
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">03<input type="checkbox" value="03"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">04<input type="checkbox" value="04"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">05<input type="checkbox" value="05"></div><br>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">06<input type="checkbox" value="06"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">07<input type="checkbox" value="07"></div>  
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">08<input type="checkbox" value="08"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">09<input type="checkbox" value="09"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">10<input type="checkbox" value="10"></div><br>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">11<input type="checkbox" value="11"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">12<input type="checkbox" value="12"></div>  
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">13<input type="checkbox" value="13"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">14<input type="checkbox" value="14"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">15<input type="checkbox" value="15"></div><br>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">16<input type="checkbox" value="16"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">17<input type="checkbox" value="17"></div>  
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">18<input type="checkbox" value="18"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">19<input type="checkbox" value="19"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">20<input type="checkbox" value="20"></div><br>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">21<input type="checkbox" value="21"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">22<input type="checkbox" value="22"></div>  
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">23<input type="checkbox" value="23"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">24<input type="checkbox" value="24"></div>
            <div class="bgcb cbbuttons">25<input type="checkbox" value="25"></div><br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul id="resultado">
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="botoes">
        <button type="button" onclick="verificar();" id="btncheckar" class="btn btn-success">Veriricar</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="limpar();" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="print();" class="btn btn-default" id="btnImprimir">Imprimir</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="campos.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

   @media print { 
          .number { visibility:hidden; } 
          form { visibility:hidden; }
          .botoes { visibility:hidden; }
          h3 { visibility:hidden; }

        #resultado {
            visibility: visible;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
    }


.content {
    width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    #number {
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 28pt;
        font-family: verdana;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .bgcb {
        width: 80px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 20pt;
        border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .bgcbchange {
        background-color: black;
    }

    #resultado {
        width: 1200px;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-family: verdana;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .item-resultado {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .botoes {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #btnImprimir {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Jefferson Ribeiro, entendi perfeitamente seu código, vejo que preciso aprender um pouco mais de sintaxe javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Segue mais um exemplo para você analisar:

```js
$('.numeros .btn input').click(function(e) {
  if ($('.numeros .btn input:checked').length > 10) {
    alert('Voce selecionou 10 numeros');
    return false;
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}).change(function() {
  if ($('.numeros .btn input:checked').length <= 10) $(this).parent('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default btn-primary');
});

$('.numeros .btn').click(function() {
  $('input', this).click();
});

$('.verificar').click(function() {
  $('.resultado').html('');
  $('.numeros .btn input').each(function(i) {
    var span = $('<span class="label"></span>').html($(this).siblings('span').html());
    $('.resultado').append(span, ' ');
    if (this.checked) span.addClass('label-primary');
    else span.addClass('label-default');
  });
});

$('.limpar').click(function() {
  $('.resultado').html('&nbsp;');
  $('.numeros .btn input').each(function(i) {
    if (this.checked) $(this).click();
  });
});

$('.imprimir').click(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
.numeros .btn,
.resultado,
.botoes {
  margin: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numeros col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
      <h1>Estudos</h1>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>01</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>02</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>03</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>04</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>05</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>06</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>07</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>08</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>09</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>10</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>11</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>12</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>13</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>14</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>15</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>16</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>17</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>18</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>19</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>20</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>21</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>22</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>23</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>24</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#"><span>25</span> <input type="checkbox"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="resultado col-xs-12 text-center">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="botoes col-xs-12 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="verificar btn btn-success">Verificar</button>
        <button type="button" class="limpar btn btn-default">Limpar</button>
        <button type="button" class="imprimir btn btn-default">Imprimir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```